# trac ticketlog.web_ui error when browsing trac

Tags: trac

I am receiving the following errors. i am using trac 0.12 on centos 5. I have plugins, advancedticketworkflow, ldaplugin, smtpldapemailsender, tracannouncer, tracwysiwg. i am trying to install commit ticket updater and similar plugins but they are not showing up. nor is it working.

```
rac[paradox:loader] ERROR: Skipping "ticketlog = ticketlog.web_ui": 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12.5-py2.4.egg/trac/loader.py", line 68, in _load_eggs
    entry.load(require=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/TracTicketChangelogPlugin-0.1-py2.4.egg/ticketlog/web_ui.py", line 45, in ?
    import json as simplejson
ImportError: No module named json
Trac[paradox:loader] ERROR: Skipping "tickettemplate = tickettemplate.ttadmin": 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12.5-py2.4.egg/trac/loader.py", line 68, in _load_eggs
    entry.load(require=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/TracTicketTemplate-0.7-py2.4.egg/tickettemplate/ttadmin.py", line 213
     with open(json_template_file) as f:
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (ttadmin.py, line 213)
Trac[paradox:loader] ERROR: Skipping "tickettemplate = tickettemplate.ttadmin": 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12.5-py2.4.egg/trac/loader.py", line 68, in _load_eggs
    entry.load(require=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/TracTicketTemplate-0.7-py2.4.egg/tickettemplate/ttadmin.py", line 213
     with open(json_template_file) as f:
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (ttadmin.py, line 213)
```

**UPDATE**

I checked out latest version, when i run setup.py i get the following error

```
python setup.py
  File "setup.py", line 55
    install_requires=['simple_json' if sys.version_info < (2, 6) else ''],
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


rpm -qa | grep -i python
python-2.4.3-19.el5
dbus-python-0.70-7.el5
python-sqlite2-2.6.3-1.el5.rf
python-iniparse-0.2.3-6.el5
libxml2-python-2.6.26-2.1.2
python-sqlite-1.1.7-1.2.1
python-elementtree-1.2.6-5
mod_python-3.2.8-3.1
MySQL-python-1.2.1-1
python-ldap-2.2.0-2.1
libselinux-python-1.33.4-2.el5
audit-libs-python-1.3.1-1.el5
rpm-python-4.4.2-37.el5
python-devel-2.4.3-19.el5
python-simplejson-2.0.9-8.el5
python-urlgrabber-3.1.0-2
postgresql-python-8.1.9-1.el5
python-json-3.4-3.el5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TracTicketChangelogPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracTicketChangelogPlugin) and [TracTicketTemplatePlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracTicketTemplatePlugin) do not support Python 2.4. TracTicketChangelogPlugin might support Python 2.4 if you install the `simplejson` package. TracTicketTemplatePlugin utilizes the `with_statement` so we'll need to add `from __future__ import with_statement` to get it to work with Python 2.5.

Comment: You could try the latest version of [TracTicketChangelogPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracTicketChangelogPlugin), some fixes were committed today. It should install `simplejson` automatically. I haven't tested it with Python 2.4, but so far I don't see anything that would prevent it from working with Python 2.4. If you have any trouble with the latest version of the plugin loading, just post the logs again and I'll see about fixing it.

Comment: i installed simpejson and json, which where already installed but got updated. the errors when away but i don't think the chnagleog is working

Comment: i think its working with the old version. i didn't commit the svn comments properly